# How target a movieClip in animate cc in this drag drop code

Tags: drag-and-drop, createjs, easeljs, flash-cc

is there a way to modify this code for animate cc to make object in the stage and interact with it ?
it is a bit of pain to make drag and drop in createjs for animate cc 
there is nothing in the web that describe how to do it for animate cc or flash cc even the documentation has nothing to tell about drag and drop in the canvas

```
//Stage
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

    //VARIABLES
    //Drag Object Size
    dragRadius = 40;
    //Destination Size
    destHeight = 100;
    destWidth = 100;

    //Circle Creation
    var label = new createjs.Text("DRAG ME", "14px Lato", "#fff");
    label.textAlign="center";
    label.y -= 7;
    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black")
    .beginFill("red").drawCircle(0,0, dragRadius);


    //Drag Object Creation
    //Placed inside a container to hold both label and shape
    var dragger = new createjs.Container();
    dragger.x = dragger.y = 100;
    dragger.addChild(circle, label);
    dragger.setBounds(100, 100, dragRadius*2, dragRadius*2);
    //DragRadius * 2 because 2*r = width of the bounding box
    var label2 = new createjs.Text("HERE", "bold 14px Lato", "#000");
    label2.textAlign = "center";
    label2.x += 50;
    label2.y += 40;


    var box = new createjs.Shape();
    box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
    var destination = new createjs.Container();
    destination.x = 350;
    destination.y = 50;
    destination.setBounds(350, 50, destHeight, destWidth);

    destination.addChild(label2, box);

    //DRAG FUNCTIONALITY =====================
    dragger.on("pressmove", function(evt){
         evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
        evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
         stage.update(); //much smoother because it refreshes the screen every pixel movement instead of the FPS set on the Ticker
         if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
           evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.2;
           box.graphics.clear();
           box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3)
           .beginStroke("#0066A4")
           .rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);

         }else{
           evt.currentTarget.alpha=1;
           box.graphics.clear();     box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
         }

    });

    //Mouse UP and SNAP====================
    dragger.on("pressup", function(evt) {
      if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
        dragger.x = destination.x + destWidth/2;
        dragger.y = destination.y + destHeight/2;
        dragger.alpha = 1;
        box.graphics.clear();     
        box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
        stage.update(evt);
      }
    });
    //Tests if two objects are intersecting
    //Sees if obj1 passes through the first and last line of its
    //bounding box in the x and y sectors
    //Utilizes globalToLocal to get the x and y of obj1 in relation
    //to obj2
    //PRE: Must have bounds set for each object
    //Post: Returns true or false
    function intersect(obj1, obj2){
      var objBounds1 = obj1.getBounds().clone();
      var objBounds2 = obj2.getBounds().clone();

      var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);

      var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
      var h2 = objBounds2.width / 2;
      var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
      var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;


      if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
      if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;

      return true;
    }


    //Adds the object into stage
    stage.addChild(destination, dragger);
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
    stage.update();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking. The demo you showed works fine (looks like it came from [this codepen](http://tinyurl.com/z8fsy96)), and it is not clear what you are trying to add. This demo was made directly in code, not with Animate CC - which is really good for building assets, animations, and display list structure, but you should write application code *around* what gets exported.

There are plenty of documentation and examples online for Drag and Drop, in the EaselJS GitHub, and EaselJS docs:

- [DragAndDrop demo in GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/DragAndDrop.html)
- [Live demo on EaselJS demos page](http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/draganddrop)
- [Documentation on pressMove](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#event_pressmove)
- [Tutorial on Mouse Events](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/) which includes Drag and Drop

I recommend narrowing down what you are trying to do, show what code or approaches you have tried so far, and posting specific questions here.

Lastly, here is the first part of an ongoing series for working with Animate CC: http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2015/04/introduction-to-the-flash-cc-html5-canvas-document.html

Cheers.

Comment: thank you so much for replying
i wanted to target the movie clip in animate cc and from there i can replace the shape made in code with the graphic i have in animate cc 
thank you

Comment: You can instantiate anything in the library using its library name. Then add it to the stage. `var s = new lib.Symbol(); stage.addChild(s);`